# Ngnix help - Multiple VM's using Nginix (ESXi with Single Public IP)?

Tags: nginx

I am currently trying to get my head around Nginx and require some guidance; This is quite new to me so apologise if this has been answered already (I did search first!).

Scenario:
I have a Seafile server (cloud.example.com) and a Zammand server (support.example.com) both on Ubuntu VM's (1 VM for each) which I have SSL'd with Certbot. I can obviously run either SSL'd but as both use port 443 I now have an issue without using Ngnix properly.

My first question is can I have another VM purely for Ngnix which will pass the url requests to other VMs or do I need both Seafile and Zammand on the same server to use Ngnix / SSL for both? (I have installed both on one VM for testing at the moment).

IF I run from a single server (both Seafile and Zammand installed - although I'd prefer each on their own VM), I'm assuming I just need to edit my "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default" and add routing paths there? Currently I have 3 "sites-available" - Seafile, Zammand and default. I see there is "sites-active" which is currently "seafile". So both cloud.example.com and support.example.com, both route to seafile (cloud.example.com)

Or am I looking at this completely wrong? Any constructive advise welcomed! Apologies if I haven't described this too clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to create a third VM and setup nginx there. You can also set it up on either of the existing VMs.

After that is done, you need to configure nginx, to use multiple "server" entries, one for each domain you are serving and directing to a different backend.

There are lots of different tutorials on how to do it on the web.

Comment: Many thanks, I found and read various sources but was still unclear if I could use a third VM as I wanted / you suggested. I will try to find more info and create a 3rd server purely for Nginx.

Comment: [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) you can find a pretty comprehensive tutorial by the authors themselves.
And if someone answers your question correctly, do mark their post as Answered, that way it's easier to know who still needs help. :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have two separate and independent servers right? If this is true, then you need to use something like SNI inspection to determine which host to proxy the connection to. This can be done without terminating the SSL connection starting with nginx 1.11.5 and the `ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module`.

You would need to configure the ProxyPass directive to allow it send the data to the remote system behind the proxy. You would then make sure that the Nginx host is on the internet so all queries go through it first.

By using SNI inspection and TCP stream proxies, the remote server handles all of it's SSL connections directly, nginx just proxy's the traffic from the one IP end-point.

I would check this out as well: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Specifically addressing the SNI inspection when using TCP Stream proxies: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html SNI is included during the TLS handshake before the handshake is actually processed, so this allows nginx to send the traffic to the right endpoint and allow that endpoint to actually do the TLS handshake.

Comment: Great stuff, thats my evening sorted for research. Much appreciated.

Comment: "So you have two separate and independent servers right? "
I have one phsyical server running ESXi and then multiple VM's. Both Seafile and Zammand are on independant VM's on the same same physical server. Does this change things?

Comment: When dealing in VM's 1 VM = 1 Server, so it doesn't really change much. You just have to make sure that the external IP can somehow get routed to the Nginx VM (probably port forwarding on the router). Then as long as Nginx can talk to the other VM's, the proxying can take place. This assumes that everything is bridged to the local network (which is typically is on ESXi)

Comment: Perfect. Yes, I'll create a new VM purely for Ngnix, forward ports 80 and 443 to it which will then route the traffic to correct VM. Thanks again.

Comment: SNI was first added to nginx 0.5.23, in 2007. I don't understand what the 1.11/1.12 comment is about.

Comment: `ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module` was added in 1.11.5 which allows nginx to perform TCP stream routing by SNI value without terminating the SSL connection.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Though, I'm not sure just proxying the raw TCP stream is the best approach here, as he won't be able to renew his Let's Encrypt certs. Or, how will `stream` handle port 80 traffic? I'd prefer to have SSL termination handled by nginx here, as well as the certs of course.

Comment: Let's Encrypt would be run on each server separately (which is likely what he's doing now). I have a setup similar to this where I just stop nginx, use the built-in server to build a giant SAN cert that gets distributed to the clients that need it. Also, you can just stream port 80 directly, or just do a basic HTTP proxy on port 80. Streaming is done per port, so one nginx can do both HTTP proxying on 80 and SSL on 443.